# Proper usage of Activity Life Cycle Events

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-event

I have two Activities, namely `MainActivity` and `Favorites`. On the `MainActivity`, I have something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //function to insert data to database
  insertData();
}
```

and I have a link on the `MainActivity` to link to `Favorites` Activity. But when clicking the Up Navigation Button from the Favorites back to the MainActivity, the app was closing.

Is it ideal to put the insertion of data to `onCreate` event?

Please help. Thank you.

Here is the log:

```
11-08 15:50:14.848: E/SQLiteLog(8746): (5) database is locked
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746): Failed to open database '/data/data/example.pangasinantranslator/databases/dbTrans'.
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:627)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:313)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:287)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:884)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at example.pangasinantranslator.MySQLiteHelper.addWord(MySQLiteHelper.java:46)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at example.pangasinantranslator.MainActivity.readFile(MainActivity.java:240)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at example.pangasinantranslator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:181)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
11-08 15:50:14.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(8746):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 15:50:14.865: D/Here is error(8746): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
11-08 15:50:14.865: D/Insert:(8746): Inserting ..
```

Comment: You can read up on an Activity life cycles [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html).

Comment: No there is no problem to insert data to `onCreate` ,but if you are finish your MainActivity after calling Favorites than when you back press your app should be close...may be this happen in your problem..

Comment: Add the Log so that we know what originally are you facing.

Comment: @NSQuamber.java on the Log, it says `Database is Locked`

Comment: as per log i beleive you are using the database connection somewhere else or you might not have closed it

Comment: you mean it is okay to put the insertion of data inside the `onCreate` event?

Comment: First thing..

If you know what you have to insert( as i don't see any data passed) then add it to DatabaseHelper's onCreate() Method

secondly if you are adding the data then check the database if you ahve got a readable database then add the data

Comment: also that i am not in favor of Activity's OnCreate Insertion

Comment: @NSQuamber.java where or when is the best time that I can close the database connection because i'm using it everytime I'm on the `MainActivity` and on the `Favorites`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40802/discussion-between-nsquamber-java-and-ajdeguzman)

Answer (score 2):

Anything that you may need to do before the screen is shown to the user should be done in `onCreate()` before `setContentView()`.